# ICEfaces v2.0.0 Internationalization problem - form is not redisplayed upon action listener call

Tags: jsf, localization, internationalization, jsf-2, icefaces

I am experiencing problems with localization.

i am using

JSF 2.0 Mojarra (xhtml not jsp) (2.02 - FCS) 
IceFaces Core 2.0.0 - beta1 
IceFaces Compatibility Library v2.0.0. - beta1

Here is the sample of the xhtml page.

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"> 
<h:head> 
<title>"#{msgs.pageTitle}"</title> 
</h:head> 
<h:body> 
<h:form> 
<br /> 
<div align="center"><h:commandButton 
value="#{msgs.serbianLatinAlphabetName}" 
actionListener="#{formSettings.swapLocale1}" immediate="true" /> <h:commandButton 
value="#{msgs.serbianChyrilicAlphabetName}" 
actionListener="#{formSettings.swapLocale1}" immediate="true" /><ice:commandButton 
value="#{msgs.pageTitle}" 
actionListener="#{formSettings.swapLocale1}" immediate="true"/></div> 
</h:form> 
</h:body> 
</html>
```

and managed bean:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import javax.faces.bean.*; 
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot; 
import javax.faces.context.*; 
import javax.faces.event.*; 

@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
public class FormSettings implements Serializable { 
private boolean isDefault = true; 
private Locale locale = new Locale("sr"); 


public void swapLocale1(ActionEvent event) { 
switchLocale(); 
} 

private void switchLocale() { 
isDefault = !isDefault; 
if (isDefault) { 
locale = new Locale("sr_ME"); 
} else { 
locale = new Locale("sr"); 
} 
//FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale); 
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
UIViewRoot myViewRoot = context.getViewRoot(); 
myViewRoot.setLocale(locale); 
} 

public Locale getLocale() { 
return locale; 
} 

public void swapLocale2(ValueChangeEvent event) { 
Boolean flag = (Boolean)event.getNewValue(); 
if (flag) { 
switchLocale(); 
} 
} 

public boolean isChecked() { 
return(false); 
} 

public void setChecked(boolean flag) {} 

}
```

my web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WePaminus</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
 <application>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>sr</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>sr_ME</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
  <resource-bundle>
   <base-name>messages</base-name>
   <var>msgs</var>
  </resource-bundle>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

The problem is that upon the click on the button, the locale is not changed. Upon manual refresh, the correct locale has been shown.

Could you please help me with this. Have to say that the same page, implemented in pure JSF  2.0  (icefaces excluded) is working perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-render the *entire* page or better, fire a **synchronous** request instead of an **asynchronous** (ajaxical) request which would only render the page partially.

Comment: Hi BalusC,

Thank you for the answer. Could you please give me an example. I thouht that actionlistener fires re-ender of the entire page. I have to say, that I see this problem only when I am using icefaces. Wtih JSF 2.0 the UI is changed according to language set in message bundle.

In the example a <f:view locale = formSettings.locale> is missing.